# Two forms and one viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel

I have two forms in one page. Both have there own properties and there own submit actions, but have some of properties in common in both forms.

Is there a way to build a view with two forms using a single viewmodel that share properties to both forms in the View?

Actually I have the fields duplicated and I have to duplicate the change of the values in both fields using jquery.

Thanks.

Comment: It can be done by having different BindingPrefix. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

you can use HtmlPrefix to achieve this.

1. I have created a model as

   ```
   public class TestModel
   {
     [Required]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     [Required]
     public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. In Controller we need to have one GetMethod but two post method for each form, but with different **BindPrefix**

   ```
   public ActionResult TestLoad()
   {
       TestModel model = new TestModel();
       return View(model);
   }

   public ActionResult TestA([Bind(Prefix = "A")]TestModel model)
   {
       return View("TestLoad",model);
   }
   public ActionResult TestB([Bind(Prefix="B")]TestModel model)
   {
       return View("TestLoad",model);
   }
   ```

   3. In the view. Here also **we need to Specify binding prefix**

   > ```
   > <table>
   >  <tr>
   >   <td>
   >     @{Html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix="A";}
   >     @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialA");}
   >   </td>
   >   <td>
   >     @{Html.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix="B";}
   >     @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialB");}
   >   </td>
   > </tr>
   > </table>
   > ```
   >
   > 4. Both partial view are exactly same , except that they post data to different actions (as defined in controller)
   > 5. Now if you run the project you should get appropriate output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks, but I think my problem is a litle diferent. Imagine that you have in your model, Name1 and Name2, and Name1 is used in PartialA and PartialB, and Name2 is only used in PartialB, how can you achieve that using your code?